# How to solve the ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND error on elastic beanstalk?

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, es6-modules

I'm trying to develope a express api with es6 style.
Everything is fine when testing on my IDE, which is win10.
Then I deploy to the EBS for production envirnoment test, It give me the ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND error.

All error given by the npm library, like cors, bcrypt, randomstring, etc. But not all library got problems.

Is it something difference when I run a es6 program on the EBS, because EBS is using linux as OS.

How can I solve it?

Here is the complete error message:

> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: > node www.js
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: ^
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'cors' imported from /var/app/current/www.js
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: at packageResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:732:9)
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:773:18)
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:887:11)
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:89:40)
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:242:28)
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: at ModuleWrap. (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:76:40)
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:75:36) {
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: }
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: npm ERR! errno 1
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: npm ERR! timesheet-api@0.0.0 start: `node www.js`
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: npm ERR! Exit status 1
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: npm ERR!
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: npm ERR! Failed at the timesheet-api@0.0.0 start script.
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> Sep  6 10:14:49 ip-172-31-26-145 web: npm ERR!     /home/webapp/.npm/_logs/2022-09-06T10_14_49_923Z-debug.log

And this is how I import the library:

```
import express from "express";
import path from "path";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import logger from "morgan";
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import passport from "passport";
import passportConfig from "./modules/passport.js";
import Debug from "debug";
import Cors from "cors";
```

Here is my full package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test-api",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "big.js": "^6.2.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "^2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "knex": "^2.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "module-alias": "^2.2.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pdfmake": "^0.2.5",
    "randomstring": "^1.2.2",
    "tedious": "^14.5.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Carl, what you could try upload a zip of your project which has cors already installed. Could you include your package.json; As I am guessing maybe cors is missing there..

Comment: @MaxVisser I provided my package.json fyi, and I will try to update the zip myself later.

Comment: Looking at your package.json I am now almost sure cors is not installed. I am guessing EB is not performing a npm install automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact reason. But I probably solve it by delete the NODE_MODULES and npm install it again. If someone face the same issue, just try the way of this.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to add a npm install to your .ebextension folder inside the build you upload to EB.

An example for a PHP Laravel application can be found here:
https://github.com/rennokki/laravel-aws-eb/blob/36df929fbd223a7feca0a6bdfd5c27f1a0aca8d6/.ebextensions/01_deploy.config#L26

You can check if this is the issue by uploading a fully installed build first.